# COMO CORTAR LECTURA DE UN EXCEL EN GENEXUS

Tags: mysql, excel, bucles, genexus, tomcat

Estoy desarrollando un programa en GX17 U11 donde a partir de un Excel que cargo desde un WebPanel, se procesa y por cada línea leída busca datos en el la DB.

El problema es el siguiente, cuando no hay más registros por leer en el Excel, continúa ejecutándose el bucle Do While.

Intenté de 2 maneras:

```
Do While &ExcelDocument.errcode = 0

   &Documento = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&fila, 1).Number
   
   Do 'process'
EndDo
```

Y el siguiente

```
&ContinueReading = true

Do While &ContinueReading = true

   &Documento = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&fila, 1).Number

   If NOT (&Documento.IsEmpty())
   
   Do 'process'
  
   Else

   &ContinueReading = false
   
   EndIf

EndDo
```

(La variable &fila va incrementando por cada línea leída en el sub 'process')

Y con ambos el bucle continúa ejecutándose. Por favor si alguien detecta algún fallo, por hacérmelo saber. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hicimos en algún caso de estos fue considerar cierta cantidad de líneas en blanco, por ejemplo 5. Si hay 5 líneas vacías se considera que se terminó el archivo

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente se utiliza el considerar que todos los campos de la línea que tienes que leer estén vacíos como indicador de finalización de lectura, habría que ver si en tu caso es posible la admisión de 0 en el campo que estás leyendo. Podrías probar con:

```
&Fila = 1 //Suponiendo que empieces a leer desde fila 1

Do While NOT &ExcelDocument.Cells(&fila,1).Number.IsEmpty()

   &Documento = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&fila,1).Number

   Do 'process' //Dentro de esta sub incrementa &Fila += 1

EndDo
```

La lógica de tu segundo código no parece tener fallas, suponiendo que la variable &Documento sea numérica y que dentro de process se incremente &Fila += 1. Restaría ver qué valores tienes en el Excel que estás leyendo.